# iTunes Connect and Facebook Analytics app install numbers are different

Tags: app-store-connect, facebook-analytics

I am having difficulty reconciling the app install count from iTunes Connect and Facebook Analytics.  I have read other posts that they are different, but in those posts iTunes is always higher.  In my case iTunes is LOWER, and never lower by a consistent amount.  This is troubling me because, obviously, I make money on the number of downloads.  How can I reconcile the two?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Apple definition of Installations:

> The total number of times your app has been installed on an iOS device with iOS 8 or later. Redownloads on the same device, downloads to multiple devices sharing the same Apple ID, and Family Sharing installations are included. App updates aren’t counted. Totals are based on app users who agree to share their data with you.

[App Analytic Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/iTunes_Connect_App_Analytics_Guide_v1.pdf)
The last sentence is makes it very clear:

> Totals are based on app users who agree to share their data with you.

So if they did't agree you won't see them in the total count.
Maybe its better to look at the App Units.

Comment: I apologize for the long delay.  This project got sidelined and now is back up.  When you say "look at the App Units", what exactly do you mean?  App Units in iTunes Connect?  I would think a way to avoid the multiple installs showing up from devices using the same Apple ID I could look at "New Users".  But still, same problem.  iTunes is showing a consistently lower number of app installs vs. FB analytics (installs or new users).